# Replace space with %20 in Url in the body of email in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created a workflow which sends some emails too.
I have put this in the body of email
`[%WorkflowContext: Current Item Url%]`
The problem is when the name of the item (for example a file) contains space, it doesn't replace them with %20. (probably for other special chars too)

Is there any solution for this `without` using Visual Studio

### Update

As Danny says in the comment, there should be String replace action but I couldn't find it too

[image]

Comment: Can't you do it with the String Replace actions in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: @DannyEngelman I couldn't find String Replace function in actions (event through search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In SharePoint Designer 2010

I found a solution to this issue. Simply highlight  `[%WorkflowContext: Current Item Url%]`
in the body of the email and click on "edit hyperlink" on the upper right hand corner; 
for "Address" click the string builder icon (three dots) and click "lookup". The "data source" is "workflow context" and "field source" is "current Item URL"; click ok. The Edit hyperlink window should have

Text to display: `[%WorkflowContext: Current Item Url%]`

Address: `[%WorkflowContext: Current Item Url%]`

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint Designer there is a Replace String action;

This is from my SPD 2013

[image]

Comment: But I don't have this on the action menu (only the top 4 items exist)